# Cleaner Syntax for HTTP Object in AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, callback

AJAX noob here... So this code below works for me which is called during an onclick event:

```
function updateText() {
  var http = getHTTPObject();    
  http.open("GET","ajax_info.asp",true);
  http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (http.readyState == 4) {
      document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=http.responseText; 
    }
  }
  http.send();      
}
```

However, when I tried to clean it like below, it no longer works. Is the code below not a correct callback syntax?

```
function handleHTTPResponse() {
  if (http.readyState == 4) {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=http.responseText;
  }
}

function updateText() {
  var http = getHTTPObject();    
  http.open("GET","ajax_info.asp",true);           
  http.onreadystatechange = handleHTTPResponse;
  http.send();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `handleHTTPResponse()` doesn't know what the `http` variable is. There's no variable declared in its scope with that name.

Pass it in as an argument

```
function handleHTTPResponse(http) {
    if (http.readyState == 4) {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=http.responseText;
    }
}

...

http.onreadystatechange = function() { handleHTTPResponse(http) };
```

Or, as pointed out by @dc5 in the other answer, use `this`

```
http.onreadystatechange = function() { handleHTTPResponse(this) };
```

Or equivalently and cleaner

```
function handleHTTPResponse() {
    if (this.readyState == 4) {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=this.responseText;
    }
}

...

http.onreadystatechange = handleHTTPResponse;
```

Or, put the function in scope so it can 'see' `http`

```
function updateText() {

    function handleHTTPResponse() {
        if (http.readyState == 4) {
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=http.responseText;
        }
    }

    var http = getHTTPObject();    
    http.open("GET","ajax_info.asp",true);           
    http.onreadystatechange = handleHTTPResponse;
    http.send();
}
```

Or, make `http` global

```
var http;    

function handleHTTPResponse() {
    if (http.readyState == 4) {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=http.responseText;
    }
}

function updateText() {
    http = getHTTPObject();    
    http.open("GET","ajax_info.asp",true);           
    http.onreadystatechange = handleHTTPResponse;
    http.send();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for showing multiple solutions.  I'm intrigued by your 3rd solution:

    `function handleHTTPResponse(http) {
    if (http.readyState == 4) {
       document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=this.responseText;
      }
    }
    
    ...
    
    http.onreadystatechange = handleHTTPResponse;`

Why is it that we do not need to pass a parameter when calling handleHTTPResponse, but the function definition seems like it's asking for an argument?  Thanks!

Comment: Oh, you don't need to pass http as an argument there (which is kind of the point) - it was a typo! corrected :)

Comment: Then, that 3rd option you have doesn't work -- it's the same syntax in the problem I mentioned because onreadystate is a child of http.

Comment: argh, another typo - proving you should never copy/paste code ;) - edited

Answer (score 1):

Your callback doesn't have access to the variable `http`, however, when called, its context is the value that variable is referencing.

Change your callback to use `this`:

```
function handleHTTPResponse() {
    if (this.readyState == 4) {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=this.responseText;
    }
}
```